# Is there easy and safe way to resize /boot

Tags: boot, server, resize

My /boot is full. Is there an easy and safe way to resize it?
I saw a discussion which said that /boot partition is not required. A /boot directory will be fine. However, I don't think I can have /boot folder while /boot is mounted.
Similarly, I can resize /boot because I can't unmount it.

I plan to
1. create a new logical volume,
2. mount it and copy all files from /boot to this new volume, and
3. change mount table to mount new logical volume under /boot.

Since it's /boot, I won't be able to boot if I make mistakes. Could anyone give me instructions?

Steve

Answer (score 6):

If it is full you can uninstall older Linux images so you can avoid the procedure of resizing/moving partitions:

Do `ls /boot` and check the "older" versions of the kernel. You can do `uname -r` to see your current kernel version (**the one you should NOT touch!**). Then for each older version run

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-<version>
```

where <*version*> is the version of the older image. For example, `ls /boot` gives me:

```
abi-3.8.0-21-generic         initrd.img-3.8.0-22-generic
abi-3.8.0-22-generic         lost+found
config-3.8.0-21-generic      memtest86+.bin
config-3.8.0-22-generic      memtest86+_multiboot.bin
Debian                       System.map-3.8.0-21-generic
extlinux                     System.map-3.8.0-22-generic
Fedora                       vmlinuz-3.8.0-21-generic
grub                         vmlinuz-3.8.0-22-generic
```

Say I want to remove version `3.8.0-21-generic` (which is older than my current one) then I run

```
sudo apt-get remove linux-image-3.8.0-21-generic
```

After it has been uninstalled I run

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

in order to finish the removal completely (for there might be things to be 'autoremoved').

Comment: I would try edwin's suggestion first, your other option is to use a boot USB and gparted to resize /boot.

Comment: @ScottGoodgame Although a very old question, I posted an answer with your suggestion which I think will benefit people searching here.

Answer (score 2):

Although [edwin's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/301147/307523) accurately describes how to [free up space on `/boot`](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot) (563 up votes) it doesn't address the question of how to incorporate `/boot` into `/` to avoid micro-management of disk space.

This question is a good example with `gparted` image:

- [How to increase size of /boot partition using gparted](https://askubuntu.com/q/671788/307523)

> Please help me here. I am always getting messages saying no free space
>   available in boot partition.

[image]

This is the [good answer by Pilot6](https://askubuntu.com/a/671796/307523) posted for that question:

> You need to boot from Ubuntu LiveUSB first.
>
> Your `sda5`, `sda6` and `sda7` partitions are inside the extended
>   `sda4` partition.
>
> You will need to extend `sda4`, then move `sda5` and `sda6` left, then
>   extend `sda7`.
>
> You will also need to re-install grub, because start sector of your
>   `/boot` partition will change. It can be done from LiveUSB by
>
> ```
> sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
> sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt/boot
> sudo chroot /mnt
> sudo grub-install /dev/sda
> exit
> ```