# How to increase size of /boot partition using gparted

Tags: boot, resize

please help me here 
i am always getting messages saying no free space available in boot partition.

[image]

output of `ls -alh /boot`

```
total 79M
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 1.0K Sep 7 20:53 .
drwxr-xr-x 23 root root 4.0K Sep 5 18:38 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.2M May 8 16:14 abi-3.16.0-38-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1.3M Aug 17 12:10 abi-4.1.6-040106-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 168K May 8 16:14 config-3.16.0-38-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 177K Aug 17 12:10 config-4.1.6-040106-generic
drwxr-xr-x 5 root root 1.0K Sep 5 14:23 grub
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 28M Aug 22 22:49 initrd.img-3.16.0-38-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 28M Aug 24 00:35 initrd.img-4.1.6-040106-generic
drwx------ 2 root root 12K Aug 12 12:52 lost+found
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 173K Mar 12 2014 memtest86+.bin
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 174K Mar 12 2014 memtest86+.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 175K Mar 12 2014 memtest86+_multiboot.bin
-rw------- 1 root root 3.4M May 8 16:14 System.map-3.16.0-38-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 3.6M Aug 17 12:10 System.map-4.1.6-040106-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 6.1M Jun 28 01:15 vmlinuz-3.16.0-38-generic
-rw------- 1 root root 6.4M Aug 17 12:10 vmlinuz-4.1.6-040106-generic
```

output of   sudo parted -l

```
Model: ATA ST9500325AS (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system     Flags
 1      1049kB  106MB  105MB   primary   ntfs            hidden
 2      106MB   140GB  140GB   primary   ntfs            boot
 3      140GB   471GB  331GB   primary   ntfs
 4      471GB   500GB  29.5GB  extended                  lba
 5      471GB   493GB  22.0GB  logical   ext4
 6      493GB   499GB  6536MB  logical   linux-swap(v1)
 7      499GB   500GB  910MB   logical   ext4
```

@Pilot6

Comment: When and by what is the message issued? I'll take a guess and say when updating the system...? There is probably not enough space on the boot partition to hold another Kernel. From the amount of used space I assume there are currently three Kernels installed. You can always remove old Kernels if you do not experience bugs with the current. Could you post the output of 'ls -alh /boot'

Comment: I think you have to select /dev/sda2 then point your mouse on the yellow rectangle and drag to increase the space of the partition, but first you have to move upwards the unallocated (713.86MB) in place of dev/sda3

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I resize my /boot partition?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/280211/how-do-i-resize-my-boot-partition)

Comment: how to remove old kernals @nephente

Comment: Better not remove any. The Kernel 3.16.0 is the official one from the Ubuntu repository. You should probably keep this. The 4.1.6 was installed by you from some other source. Having two functioning kernels available is a good thing! That way you can still boot the system if your custom kernel should fail. Best to go with Pilot6's instructions and resize the boot partition after all. Keep in mind though, that although probably everything is going to go well, you should have a recent backup at hand.

Comment: Do you boot from LiveUSB or HDD when run the commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to boot from Ubuntu LiveUSB first.

Your `sda5`, `sda6` and `sda7` partitions are inside the extended `sda4` partition.

You will need to extend `sda4`, then move `sda5` and `sda6` left, then extend `sda7`.

You will also need to re-install grub, because start sector of your `/boot` partition will change. It can be done from LiveUSB by

```
sudo mount /dev/sda5 /mnt
sudo mount /dev/sda7 /mnt/boot
sudo chroot /mnt
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
exit
```

Comment: doest it effect windows if i install grub in /dev/sda

Comment: It is already on `/dev/sda`. You just need to update it.

Comment: what is mnt  @Pilot6

Comment: `/mnt` is a directory where you will temporarily mount your partitions to do the grub update.

Comment: i am stuck sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo: unable to resolve host mint
grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for /boot (is /dev mounted?).
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install.real: error: cannot find a device for /boot/grub (is /dev mounted?

Comment: i am stuck sudo grub-install /dev/sda         
                   sudo: unable to resolve host mint
                 grub-probe: error: cannot find a device for /boot (is /dev mounted?).
Installing for i386-pc platform.  @Pilot6

Comment: I added another command for that.

Comment: error again...........sudo grub-install /dev/sda
grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.
Installing for i386-pc platform.
grub-install.real: error: failed to get canonical path of `/cow'.    @Pilot6

Comment: Boot again from LiveUSB and run these commands. I updated.

Comment: this is the output i got::::::;sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo: unable to resolve host mint
Installing for i386-pc platform.
/proc/devices: fopen failed: No such file or directory
/proc/devices: fopen failed: No such file or directory
/proc/devices: fopen failed: No such file or directory
/proc/devices: fopen failed: No such file or directory
grub-install.real: warning: Sector 32 is already in use by the program

Comment: `FlexNet'; avoiding it.  This software may cause boot or other problems in future.  Please ask its authors not to store data in the boot track.
grub-install.real: warning: Sector 49 is already in use by the program `FlexNet'; avoiding it.  This software may cause boot or other problems in future.  Please ask its authors not to store data in the boot track.
Installation finished. No error reported.
but still i am able to boot @Pilot6

Comment: Probably disk name has changed. What is output of `sudo parted -l`. And please post outputs by editing your question, not to comments.

Comment: Were the `mount`s successful? If the mountpoints do not exist yet, you will need to create them first:
`sudo mkdir -pv /mnt/{boot,dev,sys,proc}` @RishinRavi

Comment: posted the output of sudo parted -l  in the question     @Pilot6

Comment: Do you boot from LiveUSB or HDD when run this command?

Comment: i booted from HDD @Pilot6

Comment: Then you do not need to do anything, if it boots OK from HDD. That was supposed to be run from USB to fix booting. If it already boots, then there is no need.

Comment: but linux is booting from HDD.. and its works fine @nephente

Comment: @RishinRavi I posted the comment before you revealed that everything is working fine!