# How do I increase the size of /boot

Tags: boot, partitioning

I get errors trying to update. I have a HUGE SSD, so I want to **expand** /boot, **NOT** delete files there. Also, why did it give me such a small /boot?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to increase size of /boot partition using gparted](http://askubuntu.com/questions/671788/how-to-increase-size-of-boot-partition-using-gparted)

Answer (score 2):

First, see these two Ubuntu bug reports:

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unattended-upgrades/+bug/1357093
- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/1465050

A "me, too" comment is not likely to be helpful, but clicking the link that says you're affected by the bug may be, because that will increase the bug's "heat," which in turn raises the probability that developers will address the issue.

Second, resizing `/boot` is not fundamentally different from any other partition-resizing operation: You must shrink another partition, possibly move partitions to make room, and then increase the size of `/boot`. Details differ depending on your partition layout. If most of your disk space is in an LVM setup, shrinking it requires jumping through some extra hoops. There are numerous existing questions that answer these questions, such as:

- [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)
- [Why I'm seeing a lock besides the partition I'm trying to modify with gparted?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/51272/how-do-i-repartition-with-gparted)
- [How can I resize an LVM partition? (i.e: physical volume)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume)
- [How to extend my root (/) partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/492054/how-to-extend-my-root-partition)
- [How do I resize my /boot partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/280211/how-do-i-resize-my-boot-partition)
- [How to increase size of /boot partition using gparted](https://askubuntu.com/questions/671788/how-to-increase-size-of-boot-partition-using-gparted)