# Install SNMP not as easy as I thought

Tags: snmp

Looks around for how to install SNMP. Finds multiple examples:

Just run "apt-get install snmpd".....

But when I do that I get errors. I do what it says: first run ap-get install snmpd, but it fails and tells me to try "apt-get -f install", but that fails and tells me to try "apt autoremove" but that fails and tells me to try "apt-get -f install" but that fails and.... [repeats circle of fun].

Would just like to get this Linux server (Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS) running SNMP on public and port 161. Defaults basically.

Any ideas? I am new-ish to Linux. For all of the dependencies, do I just run commands like this?:

apt-get install linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic

apt-get install linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic

apt-get install linux-image-generic

apt-get install thermald

apt-get install libsnmp30

apt-get install libsnmp-base

etc... etc...

I am not fluent in Linux so if you have suggestions, please explain how to accomplish those suggestions.

Here is the exact loop I'm going through:

```
root@MYSERVER:/etc# apt-get install snmpd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
 snmpd : Depends: libsnmp30 (= 5.7.3+dfsg-1ubuntu4) but it is not going to be installed
         Depends: libsnmp-base but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@MYSERVER:/etc# apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  linux-headers-4.4.0-51 linux-headers-4.4.0-51-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-62 linux-headers-4.4.0-62-generic linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic
  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic
Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic
Suggested packages:
  fdutils linux-doc-4.4.0 | linux-source-4.4.0 linux-tools
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 198 not upgraded.
21 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/43.1 MB of archives.
After this operation, 131 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 346980 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic_4.4.0-64.85_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic (4.4.0-64.85) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic_4.4.0-64.85_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-64-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-64-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-64-generic
Preparing to unpack .../linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic_4.4.0-62.83_amd64.deb ...
Done.
Unpacking linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic (4.4.0-62.83) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic_4.4.0-62.83_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 cannot copy extracted data for './boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-62-generic' to '/boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-62-generic.dpkg-new': failed to write (No space left on device)
No apport report written because the error message indicates a disk full error
                                                                              dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-62-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-62-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-62-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-62-generic
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic_4.4.0-64.85_amd64.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic_4.4.0-62.83_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
root@MYSERVER:/etc#
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be anything to do with SNMP specifically - see [Failed to write (No space left on device)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/824759/failed-to-write-no-space-left-on-device)

Comment: I was about to edit the question and say I have no idea about the disk full error. What that error DID remind me of though is when I used Linux a few years back (12.04 I believe), but then later learned that headers (or something) fill up your hard drive and they must manually be removed with command (if you know them) or Ubuntu Tweak. Is this the case with me? When I first saw that error I wondered why anything would be downloading to a boot volume. Again, new-ish to Linux. I'll check out your link, thanks!

Comment: I have 11 TB available and things are downloading to a 230 MB partition that I must use gparted to expand? What the... Lost.

Comment: Not sure if it's OK to post a comment like this, but it relates (kind of). If not cool, moderator can delete this comment. BUT... If anyone stumbles on this, and attempting to clean up boot doesn't work for them, perhaps a solution will crop up in my new question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/886332/cleaning-up-boot-stuck-cannot-remove

Comment: is there a chance you are downloading to your swap space OR a 230MB /etc partition? Try to change to the / directory before trying again. Also, run apt-get update Very first thing to update repositories.

Comment: Switched to the / directory, got the same errors... man, this is just like the Winsxs problem with Windoh's servers. Sigh..