# Cleaning up BOOT - stuck cannot remove

Tags: boot, apt

my issue stemmed from trying to install SNMP ([Install SNMP not as easy as I thought](https://askubuntu.com/questions/886321/install-snmp-not-as-easy-as-i-thought)), but it failed, because my boot volume is full.(!?) Someone recommended to clean up boot, and my first attempt at following this ([What is the safest way to clean up /boot partition?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/345588/what-is-the-safest-way-to-clean-up-boot-partition)).... failed. Can I get a little help?

I seem to be going in the same apt-get loop as I did in my SNMP question, only this time I'm not getting DISK FULL errors, I'm getting dependency errors. So, I try to apt-get remove the listed dependency, and get more dependency errors, to the point where... I'm lost, and have almost forgotten why I'm doing this in the first place. My latest:

```
root@MYSERVER:/dev/mapper# uname -r
4.4.0-45-generic
root@MYSERVER:/dev/mapper# dpkg --list 'linux-image*' | grep ^ii
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic        4.4.0-45.66   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic        4.4.0-51.72   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic        4.4.0-53.74   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic        4.4.0-57.78   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic        4.4.0-59.80   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-45-generic  4.4.0-45.66   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic  4.4.0-51.72   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic  4.4.0-53.74   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic  4.4.0-57.78   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
root@MYSERVER:/dev/mapper# sudo apt-get remove linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@MYSERVER:/dev/mapper# sudo apt-get remove linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic but it is not going to be installed
                       Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
root@MYSERVER:/dev/mapper# dpkg --list 'linux-image*' | grep ^ii
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-45-generic        4.4.0-45.66   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-51-generic        4.4.0-51.72   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-53-generic        4.4.0-53.74   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic        4.4.0-57.78   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-4.4.0-59-generic        4.4.0-59.80   amd64        Linux kernel image for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-45-generic  4.4.0-45.66   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-51-generic  4.4.0-51.72   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-53-generic  4.4.0-53.74   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic  4.4.0-57.78   amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 4.4.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
root@MYSERVER:/dev/mapper#
```

Comment: Hmm, I read that "sudo dpkg --list 'linux-image*' | grep ^ii" makes it a little easier to see just the installed kernels. Am I attempting to delete/remove kernels that are in use and instead should be running that command without "grep ^ii" and then remove kernels NOT listed/revealed when using that grep option?

Comment: Try in one command: `sudo apt-get remove linux-image-4.4.0-57-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-57-generic`

Comment: You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-62-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-62-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-4.4.0-64-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-4.4.0-64-generic but it is not going to be installed
Recommends: thermald but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Comment: ...then I do "apt-get -f install" and get stuck in the no space left loop ----> failed to write (No space left on device)