# Removing boot packages while ignoring dependencies

Tags: boot, apt, package-management, dependencies

My boot folder is full, and according to [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/301143/is-there-easy-and-safe-way-to-resize-boot) one simple solution is to remove old Linux image packages. Unfortunately, I can't do this because apt tells me that some of my packages have unmet dependencies – those dependencies, of course, need to be installed into /boot.

Is there any way around this? I'm hesitant to just manually delete files from the boot partition.

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-68-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-68-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-extra-3.13.0-73-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-73-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-image-generic : Depends: linux-image-3.13.0-73-generic but it is not going to be installed
 linux-server : Depends: linux-generic (= 3.13.0.73.79) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I had the same problem today.

Fixed it by moving one of the old kernel images from the boot folder to a temp location to free up a little bit of space.

Then try the other solution again.

Regards,
Dori